# Tick boxes for a qgis plugin written in python

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

in a python plugin for qgis I want the user to be able to select one or more of several options via tick boxes.

I imagine it to look like e.g. Qgis 2.2 tool "Vector" -> "Data Management Tools" -> "Join attributes by location". In the "Attribute Summary" section of this tool the user is able to tick several functions on and off:

[image]

At the moment I use a string input (`##options=string "option1,option2,option3"`). The user has to enter all options separated by a comma. This works but it does not look very pretty.

Is this possible with Pyhton? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. I think you are looking for a [checkbox](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcheckbox.html).

```
self.yourCheckbox = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.layoutWidget)
self.yourCheckbox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Checkboxname"))
```

Then to see if its checked:

```
isitchecked = self.dlg.ui.yourCheckbox.isChecked() # returns True if checked
```